# How can I create Binary Search to work with ArrayList from scratch?

Tags: java, search, arraylist, binary

So I need to write a code from beginning by my own without using Collection or any shortcut, the thing is, I got this one code for binary search but it's for Array.. can I know if there is a way to recreate or change something to make it work with ArrayList? thanks

```
public class binarySearch {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        int target = 42;
        
        int arr[] ={10,14,19,26,27,31,33,35,42,44};
        
        int left = 0;
        int right = arr.length -1;
        
        int mid = 0;
        
        while(left<right){
            mid =  (left + right)/2;
            
            if(arr[mid] == target){
                System.out.println("Location for "+target+" is "+mid);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if(target<arr[mid]){
                right = mid -1 ;
            }
            else{
                left = mid + 1;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be a straightforward translation.  Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: "I got this one code", so you didn't even write that code yourself?

Comment: I'm really beginner at this.. I'm sorry

Comment: An ArrayList is part of the java collections framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are equivalents of list operations for array operations:

```
arr.length => list.size()
arr[i] => list.get(i)
```

Just replace the fragments of code and it should work.

Comment: I'm just start confuse at if(arr[mid]==target)..how im suppose to change that equation to arrayList?

Comment: `list.get(mid)` assuming you list variable is called `list`

Comment: Because whenever i type if(list.get(mid) == target) , it give me error..

Comment: Probably your List does not have declared type. You should use `List<Integer>` or `ArrayList<Integer>`